# Postgres query for matrix table

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, matrix

I want to make a query in MySQL or postgres that will be generated from 4 tables.

Please see the following tables.

I want postgres or sql query for matrix table that is defined below.

How can I achieve this using SQL?

Thank you a lot in advance.

**table: Targets**

```
+----+-------------+
| id | name        |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | 9999999991  |
|  2 | 9999999992  |
|  3 | 9999999993  |
|  4 | 9999999994  |
|  5 | 9999999995  |
|  6 | 9999999996  |
|  7 | 9999999997  |
|  8 | 9999999998  |
+----+-------------+
```

**table: Target_groups**

```
+----+-------------+
| id | name        |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | Group 1     |
|  2 | Group 2     |
|  3 | Group 3     |
|  4 | Group 4     |
+----+-------------+
```

**table: Target_groups_map**

```
+----+-----------+--------------+
| id |targets    | target_groups|
+----+-----------+--------------+
|  1 | 9999999991|    1         |
|  2 | 9999999992|    1         |
|  3 | 9999999993|    2         |
|  4 | 9999999994|    2         |
|  5 | 9999999995|    3         |
|  6 | 9999999996|    3         |
|  6 | 9999999997|    4         |
|  6 | 9999999998|    4         |
+----+-----------+--------------+
```

**table: Call_details**

```
+----+-----------+--------------+
| id | caller    | called       |
+----+-----------+--------------+
|  1 | 9999999995| 9999999996   |
|  2 | 9999999992| 9999999998   |
|  3 | 9999999993| 9999999998   |
|  4 | 9999999994| 9999999991   |
|  5 | 9999999995| 9999999998   |
|  6 | 9999999996| 9999999992   |
|  6 | 9999999991| 9999999993   |
|  6 | 9999999992| 9999999998   |
+----+-----------+--------------+
```

**Matrix table** that I want

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|        | Group 1| Group 2| Group 3| Group 4|
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| Group 1|     -  |     1  |     -  |     2  |
| Group 2|     1  |     -  |     -  |     1  |
| Group 3|     1  |     -  |     1  |     1  | 
| Group 4|     -  |     -  |     -  |     -  |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: Do you need help with the `JOINs`?  Or with the "pivoting"?  Or both?

Comment: I need only desired output. You can use either join or pivot.

Comment: You will need both.  I was checking to see if you could do one part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Postgres you need the extension [`tablefunc`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/tablefunc.html) to generate *pivot* table:

```
create extension if not exists tablefunc;
```

The query with `crosstab()`:

```
select * from crosstab($$
    select t1.name caller_name, t2.name called_name, count
    from target_groups t1
    cross join target_groups t2
    left join (
        select c1, c2, count(*)::int
        from (
            select g1.target_groups c1, g2.target_groups c2
            from call_details c
            join target_groups_map g1 on c.caller = g1.targets
            join target_groups_map g2 on c.called = g2.targets
            ) c
        group by 1, 2
        order by 1, 2
        ) c
    on t1.id = c1 and t2.id = c2
$$) 
as ct (" " text, "Group 1" int, "Group 2" int, "Group 3" int, "Group 4" int)

         | Group 1 | Group 2 | Group 3 | Group 4 
---------+---------+---------+---------+---------
 Group 1 |         |       1 |         |       2
 Group 2 |       1 |         |         |       1
 Group 3 |       1 |         |       1 |       1
 Group 4 |         |         |         |        
(4 rows)
```

The same query with the aggregate function [`string_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-aggregate.html) instead of `crosstab()`:

```
select caller_name as " ", string_agg(coalesce(count::text, '-'), ', ') matrix
from (
    select t1.name caller_name, t2.name called_name, count
    from target_groups t1
    cross join target_groups t2
    left join (
        select c1, c2, count(*)::int
        from (
            select g1.target_groups c1, g2.target_groups c2
            from call_details c
            join target_groups_map g1 on c.caller = g1.targets
            join target_groups_map g2 on c.called = g2.targets
            ) c
        group by 1, 2
        order by 1, 2
        ) c
    on t1.id = c1 and t2.id = c2
    ) sub
group by 1
order by 1;

         |   matrix   
---------+------------
 Group 1 | -, 1, -, 2
 Group 2 | 1, -, -, 1
 Group 3 | 1, -, 1, 1
 Group 4 | -, -, -, -
(4 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL...

It's a challenge.  I will walk through the 2 steps needed:

First, let's build (and debug) a query that lists all the caller-called pairs, some of them duplicated.  (We'll count them later.)

```
SELECT ger.name AS er_name,
       ged.name AS ed_name
FROM Call_details AS cd
JOIN Target_groups_map AS mer  ON mer.targets = cd.caller
JOIN Target_groups_map AS med  ON med.targets = cd.called
JOIN Target_groups AS ger ON ger.id = mer.target_groups
JOIN Target_groups AS ged ON ged.id = med.target_groups;
```

Second, let's do the pivot, count the dups, default to '-', etc:

```
SELECT
er_name                               AS '',
IFNULL(SUM(ed_name = 'Group 1'), '-') AS 'Group 1',
IFNULL(SUM(ed_name = 'Group 2'), '-') AS 'Group 2',
IFNULL(SUM(ed_name = 'Group 3'), '-') AS 'Group 3',
IFNULL(SUM(ed_name = 'Group 4'), '-') AS 'Group 4'
FROM ( ... ) AS y
GROUP BY er_name;
```

For the '...' put the entire query from the first step (don't include the `;`').

The `SUM` may seem strange, but here's how that works:  The boolean expression inside it turns into 0 (false) or 1 (true), then `SUM` effectively counts.

If the number of Groups is not exactly 4, then you should abandon trying to do this in SQL.  Sure, it could be done with a really convoluted stored procedure to construct the second query, but that makes my brain hurt.

Whenever I do pivoting, I write the code in the client language, such as PHP.

Answer (score 0):

This sql statement:

```
SELECT 
  tg1.name as caller, 
  tg2.name as called, 
  SUM(cd.caller IS NOT NULL AND cd.called IS NOT NULL) as cnt 
FROM 
  Target_groups tg1 JOIN Target_groups tg2   
  LEFT JOIN 
    Target_groups_map tgm1 ON tg1.id=tgm1.target_groups
  LEFT JOIN 
    Target_groups_map tgm2 ON tg2.id=tgm2.target_groups
  LEFT JOIN
    Call_details cd ON tgm1.targets=cd.caller AND tgm2.targets=cd.called
GROUP BY
  tg1.id,tg2.id;
```

Gives:

```
+---------+---------+------+
| caller  | called  | cnt  |
+---------+---------+------+
| Group 1 | Group 1 |    0 |
| Group 1 | Group 2 |    1 |
| Group 1 | Group 3 |    0 |
| Group 1 | Group 4 |    2 |
| Group 2 | Group 1 |    1 |
| Group 2 | Group 2 |    0 |
| Group 2 | Group 3 |    0 |
| Group 2 | Group 4 |    1 |
| Group 3 | Group 1 |    1 |
| Group 3 | Group 2 |    0 |
| Group 3 | Group 3 |    1 |
| Group 3 | Group 4 |    1 |
| Group 4 | Group 1 |    0 |
| Group 4 | Group 2 |    0 |
| Group 4 | Group 3 |    0 |
| Group 4 | Group 4 |    0 |
+---------+---------+------+
```

But if you want formatted EXACTLY how you have it printed out you'll need a prepared sql statement and then do what Mr Rick James says, if you need it dynamic (dont know the Group names beforehand) here is a starting point:

```
SET @sql = NULL; SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(CONCAT('"" as ',quote(name)))) INTO @sql FROM Target_groups; SET @sql = CONCAT("SELECT Target_groups.name, ", @sql, " FROM Target_groups"); PREPARE stmt FROM @sql; EXECUTE stmt;

Statement prepared

+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| name    | Group 1 | Group 2 | Group 3 | Group 4 |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| Group 1 |         |         |         |         |
| Group 2 |         |         |         |         |
| Group 3 |         |         |         |         |
| Group 4 |         |         |         |         |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

ps - this is to help anyone trying to solve this + test:

```
create table Targets (id int, name bigint) engine=innodb;
insert into Targets values (1,9999999991),(2,9999999992),(3,9999999993),(4,9999999994),(5,9999999995),(6,9999999996),(7,9999999997),(8,9999999998);

create table Target_groups (id int, name varchar(16)) engine=innodb;
insert into Target_groups values (1,'Group 1'),(2,'Group 2'),(3,'Group 3'),(4,'Group 4');

create table Target_groups_map (id int,targets bigint,target_groups int) engine=innodb;
insert into Target_groups_map values (1,9999999991,1),(2,9999999992,1),(3,9999999993,2),(4,9999999994,2),(5,9999999995,3),(6,9999999996,3),(6,9999999997,4),(6,9999999998,4);

create table Call_details (id int,caller bigint,called bigint) engine=innodb;
insert into Call_details values (1,9999999995,9999999996),(2,9999999992,9999999998),(3,9999999993,9999999998),(4,9999999994,9999999991),(5,9999999995,9999999998),(6,9999999996,9999999992),(6,9999999991,9999999993),(6,9999999992,9999999998);
```

Answer (score -1):

I made a query:

```
Select A.name as caller,A.ToGroupName as called,Count(phone_number) as count
From (
                Select G.id,T.phone_number,G.Name,FC.Called,TG.name as ToGroupName
                From targets T
                LEFT Join target_groups_map GM on GM.targets = T.phone_number
                Left Join target_groups G on G.id = GM.target_groups
                INNER Join call_details FC on FC.Caller = T.phone_number
                INNER Join target_groups_map TGM on TGM.targets = FC.called
                Inner Join target_groups TG on TG.id = TGM.target_groups
) A
Group By A.name,A.ToGroupName
Order By A.name,A.ToGroupName
```

Gives output:

```
+---------+---------+------+
| caller  | called  | cnt  |
+---------+---------+------+
| Group 1 | Group 2 |    1 |
| Group 1 | Group 4 |    3 |
| Group 1 | Group 5 |    2 |
| Group 2 | Group 1 |    2 |
| Group 2 | Group 4 |    1 |
| Group 2 | Group 5 |    3 |
| Group 3 | Group 1 |    1 |
| Group 3 | Group 3 |    1 |
| Group 3 | Group 4 |    1 |
| Group 3 | Group 5 |    1 |
| Group 4 | Group 2 |    1 |
| Group 5 | Group 2 |    2 |
+---------+---------+------+
```

converted it into matrix format